# Django how to only allow specific users to see a page

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

my models.py

```
class Utilizador(AbstractBaseUser):
   id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
   departamentoid = models.ForeignKey(Departamento, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='DepartamentoID', blank=True, null=True)
   email = models.CharField(db_column='Email', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
   nome = models.CharField(db_column='Nome', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Inscrio(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
   utilizadorid = models.ForeignKey('Utilizador', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='UtilizadorID')
   participanteinfoid = models.ForeignKey('Participanteinfo', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ParticipanteinfoID')
```

my view.py

```
def ver_col(request, pk):
   user = Utilizador.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
   insc = Inscrio.objects.get(utilizadorid=request.user.id)

   if  request.user.is_authenticated:
       if request.user.id==insc.utilizadorid.id:
           return render(request, 'main/ver_col.html', 
                        {
                         "insc": insc
                        })
```

So, I want users to see this "ver_col.html" but they are only allowed to enter the pages with the UtilizadorID (of the table Inscrio) associated with the user logged in at the moment (request.user.id or request.user).

Basically I want all users to be able to see the template but only their own data

Comment: What about your current code isn't doing that? Do you mean you want all users to be able to see the template but only their own data?

Comment: Are you getting errors or something with the code? Not clear on what the issue is.

Comment: yes @MichaelHawkins (to the first question)

Comment: It looks like your code is doing that. What is the problem with it?

Comment: I have a pk in the views

Comment: I can see my own data, but in the url if I change the pk for another number I can see the data of other users. Like if I enter my data with /ver_col/10 and change /ver_col/11 I can see even if it isnt from the authenticated user

Comment: I don't see how that's possible with what you posted - you aren't even using the pk variable in your code anywhere to get the objects.

Comment: Are you using caching or something like that? Otherwise I don't see why your code doesn't work - you aren't using the PK to get the objects from the database.

Comment: I dont get either, tbh

Comment: There has to be something else somewhere in your code that is not posted here. What you've shown should not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve, but if the pk is user Model's pk then,

```
if request.user.id== pk
```

meaning the current logged in user is viewing its own page only and some other users page.
This should go after you have authenticated the user.